# "final let" purpose in Swift, is it not redundant?

Tags: swift

Is it not redundant to use `final let` as `let` is already a constant and can not be modified? In which cases is that useful?

Comment: AFAIK, it's totally redundant – arguably the compiler should emit a diagnostic.

Comment: @Hamish I thought too, but the compiler doesn't complain, try `final let x:String = "x"`

Comment: @FelipeSantiago redundant doesn't mean it's an error. It just means it's superfluous.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen indeed Claus, just waiting a little more to accept your answer, thx

Comment: @FelipeSantiago Sure, I'm not saying that the compiler does emit a diagnostic, only that it probably ought to :)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Worth noting that the compiler emits an error for other redundant decl modifiers, e.g `final static let x = 0`.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Could you provide an example? A `let` property cannot be overriden by a computed property (as that could violate the fact that a `let` property's value never changes), and Swift doesn't allow overrides to introduce storage.

Comment: @Hamish I think like Claus, a let can't be changed like a var, maybe unless you don't initialize the let in the class, but in the override, I'll test later

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means the variable won't be dynamically dispatched, [which can improve performance](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27).

However, if you declare your class final, it's redundant to declare the individual variables/members of that class final.

Comment: A (non-dynamic) `let` property shouldn't be dynamically dispatched regardless of whether it's marked `final`.

Comment: @Hamish I'm not sure you can 100% say that because of Objective-C, but regardless, I think Apple's blog post about it is a better source of truth than any of my own anecdotal statements.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that final is better applied to classes than individual members. Where it _will_ increase performance, as any class inhering from NSObject will be dynamically dispatched otherwise (and the need to do so is still super common in macOS, but also iOS, development)

Comment: The only way Obj-C would impact how Swift dispatches to a `let` property is if it were marked `dynamic`, in which case yes message dispatch would be used, but I was talking about a non-dynamic property :) If we're talking about how Obj-C would dispatch to it if it were `@objc`, then it would use message dispatch regardless of whether it's marked as `final` in Swift. In either case, IMO the answer "It means the variable won't be dynamically dispatched" to the question "in which case is [using `final let`] useful?" is misleading.

Comment: @Hamish fair point (and good comment), but I think we can let the reference to Apple's in-depth explanation stand, as I'm certain people would ask this question with little thoughts to `let` versus `var`. (Also, I want more Swift developers to write `final class ...`)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Using a `final class` would do absolutely nothing to improve performance if you're using whole module optimization. The optimizer would see that there are no overriding classes, so it can devirtualize virtualized calls, as if they were `final`.

Comment: @Alexander The declaration of intent of making a class final is standard practise is practically all other mainstream programming languages (where it's an option), _potential_ performance improvements is just _one_ of the good things it offers.

Comment: @Alexander also, bottom of linked article, it explains how it can't be inferred for public functions/classes. For anyone who is making anything larger than an app for their homework, it's likely you'll have to create separate modules (dynamic libraries), where the use of public/final is suddenly very relevant.